# std::atomic.compare_and_exchange_strong() fails

Tags: c++, c++11

I am pretty new to C++ and have to do some exercises on atomic operations.
I am implementing a AtomicHashSet - but I get confused by `compare_and_exchange_strong()`behaving different than I would expect it.

As internal data structure I use an array of std::atomic-instances:

```
std::atomic<Item<T>> data[N] = {};
```

The essential part observing the problems is the following:

```
bool insert(const T &key) {
    if (keysStored.load() == N) {
        return false;
    }

    size_t h = this->hash(key);



    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        size_t pos = (h + i) % N;
        data[pos].load(); //No idea why that is needed...
        Item<T> atPos = data[pos].load();

        if (atPos.dataRef == &key) {
            return false;
        }
        if (atPos.dataRef == nullptr && atPos.state == BucketState::Empty) {
            Item<T> atomDesired(&key, BucketState::Occupied);

            if (data[pos].compare_exchange_strong(atPos, atomDesired)) {
                keysStored++;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

`Item` is defined like this:

```
enum class BucketState { Empty, Occupied, Deleted };

template<typename T>
struct Item {
Item(): dataRef(nullptr), state(BucketState::Empty) {}
Item(const T* dataRef, BucketState state) : dataRef(dataRef), state(state) {}

const T* dataRef;
BucketState state;
};
```

I do some assertion tests (inserting an element twice, checking `keyStored`etc.). With this code they succeed - but if I remove the nonsense `data[pos].load();` call they fail due to `compare_exchange_strong()` returning `false`. This strange failing behavior occurs only the first time the function is called...

I also checked with a debugger - the value of atPos is the same as in `data[pos]` - so in my understanding ces should do the exchange and returjn `true`.

Another question: Do I have to use a special memory order to ensure atomic (and therefore threadsafe) behaviour?

Comment: What's the definition of `Item`?

Comment: NB [atomics.types.generic]/1.

Comment: There's nothing wrong per se about compare-exchange failing. It will fail every time someone else got there first.

Comment: I know - but at the moment there is nobody else there

Comment: It would be great to have a complete example that can be compiled, rather than snippets of incomplete code.

Comment: In any event, `Item` should look like this:  `template <typename T> struct Item { constexpr Item() noexcept : Item(nullptr, Empty) {} constexpr Item(const T* p, BucketState s) noexcept : dataRef(p), state(s) {} /* ... */ };`

Comment: And make sure you compile with `-march=native`.

Comment: What compiler and what platform are you using?

Comment: I am using `clang` (Apple LLVM Vesion 7.0.0, bundled with newest XCode) on Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to say without a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but the problem arises most probably due to padding. `std::atomic.compare_and_exchange_strong` conceptually uses `memcmp` to compare the current state with the expected one. Due to alignment requirements, the size of your `Item`structure will be 16 bytes on a 64 bit machine (two pointers) but only 12 of them actually contribute to its value (8 for the pointer and 4 for the enum).

So the statement

```
Item<T> atPos = data[pos].load();
```

only copies the first 12 bytes, but `std::atomic.compare_and_exchange_strong` will compare all 16. To solve this you could explicitly specify the underlying type of BucketState to be an integral type that has the same size as a pointer (usually size_t and uintptr_t have that property).

E.g. Item could look like this:

```
enum class BucketState :size_t { Empty, Occupied, Deleted };

template<typename T>
struct Item {
    const T* dataRef;
    BucketState state;

    static_assert(sizeof(const T*) == sizeof(BucketState), "state should have same size as dataRef");
};
```

I can't tell you however, why using the statement `data[pos].load();` makes a difference. If I'm not mistaken, your implicit call to std::memcmp causes undefined behavior, as it will read uninitialized memory.

> Another question: Do I have to use a special memory order to ensure atomic (and therefore threadsafe) behaviour?

The short answer is no, you don't need to.

The long answer is that first of all, accesses to std::atomics are always thread safe and atomic (those are not the same). Memory ordering become relevant, when you want to use those atomics to guard access to non-atomic shared memory (like `if (dataAvalialbe) //readSharedmemory`). However, the default memory ordering for all operations on atomics is memory_order_seq_cst, which is the strongest there is.

Comment: The only thing that first `data[pos].load();` does is act as a inter-thread synchronization  point, but I don't see how it's actually needed at all when he does another load right after.

Comment: @user2296177: If I had to guess, I woudl say that after `data[pos].load();` the memory region in which the uninitialized part of `atPos` will reside has a different value (e.g. zero). Effectively what the OP does is undefined behavior, because the `memcmp` in `compare_and_exchange_strong` will read uninitialized memory

Comment: The enum is likely 4 bytes (the default underlying type for a scoped enum is `int`).

Comment: That solved my problem - thank you! I am still wondering why the additional call to load() makes a difference...

Comment: @FlorianLoch: See my comment to user2296177, but it is really only a guess. One would have to look at the generated assembler code

Comment: +1. Also, the note in [\[atomics.types.operations.req\]/26](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.types.operations.req#26) is directly on point.