# compare_exchange_strong failing despite data matching expected value

Tags: c++, c++11, icc, stdatomic

The issue is with a `compare_exchange_strong` returning false, despite the underlying data being equal to `expected`. e.g.:

```
std::atomic<data> ptr;
...
auto ptr_data = ptr.load();
bool cmp_result = memcmp(&ptr_data, &expected, sizeof(ptr_data));
bool cas_result = ptr.compare_exchange_strong(expected, desired);
assert(cas_result || !cmp_result);
```

`data` is a 128-bit POD. `ptr.is_lock_free()` returns true. This is tested in a single-threaded fashion. `cas_result` is always false, `cmp_results` always true.

Compilation is done with Intel's C++ compiler, version 16 update 2. On Linux, libstdc++ version 5.3.1. 64-bit binary. 
Exactly the same code used to work correctly when compiled on Windows, with same ICC16 but as 32-bit code. This makes me believe it is the stdlib implementation quirk.

Thank you

Comment: That's my bad, please ignore that. The example is written from memory. The values were compared by the debugger before the CAS. Updated.

Comment: Hmm, OK. The library's implementation just defers to a compiler intrinsic, `__atomic_compare_exchange`, so I doubt that it's a library issue.

Comment: I think you're calling `memcmp` wrongly - the argments are already pointers to the compared data, why are you passing them as pointers to pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this situation as well on a struct I was using. I think it was caused by padding bits inserted due to alignment issues and the fact that compare_exchange does a bitwise comparison of the two values.

On my machine, the word/pointer size is 8 bytes and the struct I had was something like this:

```
struct s {
    int i;
    void *ptr;

};
```

which used only 12 bytes to represent its contents (ptr was 8 bytes, int was 4), but it's size was of 16 bytes (sizeof(s) == 16). What I did was change the struct into:

```
struct s {
    long long i;
    void *ptr;
};
```

Because long long is 8 bytes on my machine, this version had a 16 bytes size and they were all used to represent the actual value (no padding bits).

I saw the problem after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33974075/9666170) answer, which might be more detailed.

Comment: memcmp is *supposed* to also be a bitwise compare of the full object representation, including padding, I think.  But I assume the problem is that ICC optimizes the memcmp into just comparing the values for equality.  Suggestion: use `intptr_t` or `ptrdiff_t` to get an int that's as wide as a pointer, for either 32 or 64-bit mode.  So it's always two equal-sized members, and can be only 8 bytes if you ever compile as 32-bit or for a 64-bit ILP32 ABI like Linux x32 or AArch64's ILP32.