# What is the correct and optimal implementation of atomic_ref and atomic with padding bits?

Tags: x86, c++20, micro-optimization, stdatomic

TL;DR: Should `std::atomic` CAS with padding bits zero padding bits in constructor, or deal with them via CAS retries / masked LL/SC? Consider also `atomic_ref` CAS, and atomic wait for both `atomic` and `atomic_ref`.

---

Some trivial types in C++ do not have unique_representation, `std::has_unique_object_representations_v` is false for them, it means, that values that are equivalent may not `memcmp` bit-wise equal.

One of reasons for that is having padding bits. Padding bits are unused bit-field bits, structure alignment bytes, or extra padding for, say, 10-byte float.

C++2a has excluded padding `atomic<T>::compare_exchange_strong` and `compare_exchange_weak` comparison. See:

- Main proposal [P0528R3
  The Curious Case of Padding Bits, Featuring Atomic Compare-and-Exchange](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0528r3.html)
- Link from `atomic_ref` [5. Concern with atomic and padding bits in T](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0019r8.html#concern-with-atomict-and-padding-bits-in-t)

---

Now the question is, how can this be correctly and efficiently implemented, especially taking into account having `atomic_ref`. x86 support only bitwise equality in CAS, I expect it is similar with other CPU architectures.

- One way to do it is to clear padding bits form source value in constructor, `store`, `exchange`, and clear the desired value in `compare_exchange_*`. This way it seems that `atomic_ref` constructor has to be atomic, and there's a "pay for something you don't use", if compare_exchange operation is not used.
- Another way I see is to copy the padding bits from observed value in `compare_exchange` loop. So CAS loop would exit only in value bits mismatch. This seem to defeat the purpose of the division between strong and weak CAS, since weak CAS should not consistently fail, and with this approach it may. Although LL/SC-based CAS seem to be able to do its inner comparison with padding bit naturally excluded, so weak CAS without loop is possible.

So the questions here are:

- Which of the approaches (if any) is correct? Are there other correct approaches?
- If multiple approaches are correct, which is generally more efficient?

Note that `atomic<T>::wait` / `atomic_ref<T>::wait` also has to deal with padding bits, and the approach has to be shared.

---

Note that there is an easy way to obtain non-zero padding bits:

```
struct S {
  int i : 17;
};
S* s = (S*)malloc(sizeof(S));
s->i = 1;

struct S2 {
  std::uint8_t  j;
  std::uint16_t k;
};

S2* s2 = (S2*)malloc(sizeof(S2));
s2->j = 2;
...
s2->k = 3;
```

Comment: In your example, how are you going to do that 17-bit store, though?  The obvious way would be as a single dword store.  `sizeof(S)` is 4, not 3.  In general, I think storing the member before the padding can also write the padding with minimal loss of efficiency, unless you have an `alignas(32)` member or something.  But then it's too large for lock-free atomics.  And if you don't write that member at all, it's UB to read the whole object.  Unions of different-size members could be a problem, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Compilers would avoid writing bits to non-value: https://godbolt.org/z/K5MGzE , also I've added another example when writing the whole structure does not make sense.

Comment: Hmm, smells like a missed optimization to me.  Unless I'm forgetting something about bitfield rules for padding bits, I don't see what's stopping the compiler from simply choosing to step on the padding bits.  Interesting observation though that compilers in practice don't do that.

Comment: @Peter, I think it is due to the fact that normally you don't have _just one_ consecutive bit field, as you use them for _packing_, so compilers have to mask values. And on the other hand, at least msvc really works with bit fields far worse than with manually written bit ops on integers. (So in my code I'd just use `atomic<uintNN_t>` to fit all bits. The problem mostly concerns me as the problem of correct atomic wait implementation; atomic wait decision has to follow CAS decision)

Comment: Of course *normally* you have to mask, but when writing the member that's adjacent to the padding, you can zero the padding along with it.  Sometimes (like here), that would make it much more efficient.  I think that might be a sufficient rule to implement C++20 as written, which requires the compare to act on the value, not necessarily equivalent to memcmp. At least for std::atomic, if not for atomic_ref.

Comment: It sounds like a good idea, but it looks like compiler ABI change to require compilers doing the opposite to what they are doing. Also this rule probably should not go too far, consider `struct alignas(64) { atomic<unsigned> queue_index; }` with 60 bytes of padding.

Comment: Good point that it'd be an ABI change.  But re: large structs, you'd only do this for objects <= 16 bytes on x86-64; ones small enough for lock cmpxchg16b.  Otherwise you need to fall back to locking anyway.  (Of course, a generic non-lock-free CAS would presumably use memcmp, causing the issue to rear its head again.  Pass a compare callback to the libatomic function?)  IDK man, this C++20 change seems like a mess for `atomic_ref` to implement efficiently.  It seems fine for `atomic<T>` whose constructor can just make sure the object is fully initialized, though.

Comment: Constructor of `atomic` does not help, unless the values passed to `store` `exchange` or `cas` are patched before assigning. (And if going with ABI change proposal, then constructor of `atomic` doesn't need any special care). 

Though the change us meant to fix `struct` with padding, to me the best part is defeating "what if `int` and `void*` have padding on DeathStation 9000?" language-layering.

Comment: I guess that if there's a need for type-erased support for this feature, need masked version of each atomic operation, the mask is computed from compiler's equivalent of MSVC `__builtin_zero_non_value_bits` and goes as separate parameter. This could also be a way for LL/SC intrinsic that would do `(expected ^ observed) & value_mask` instead of `expected == observed` internally.

Comment: Yeah, I started editing my answer to suggest this, and realized that store, exchange, and CAS would all have to sanitize / canonicalize every new value.  But the values are always in registers when these functions inline, so it shouldn't be costly in the final asm, and only needs to happen at all for objects with padding bits.  "Just" a potential matter of compiler technology, and yeah this C++20 change might need an ABI change to support efficiently.  (BTW, you might want to unaccept my answer, it doesn't fully answer the question now that I've read the C++20 change.)

Answer (score 3):

**The `atomic_ref<T>` *constructor* should always be trivial, not touching the referenced object**.  Nobody wants an extra atomic store or RMW to clear the padding bits on the off chance that they're non-zero.  `atomic_ref` is designed to be re-constructed every time you want to access an object atomically.  It *needs* to optimize away.

Also, we don't want to make code using non-atomic objects slower just in case something somewhere might use atomic_ref.

(That said, if the padding is a whole number of *bytes*, those could be stored to with 1 or more plain store(s) before a CAS.  Nothing (except raw CAS instructions) should ever depend on what values are read from those padding bits / bytes so it doesn't matter if there's potential for tearing of the object representation.  The padding isn't part of the `T` value, so the value can't be torn.)

---

**I don't see any clear way to implement everything efficiently for `atomic_ref<T>`; objects with non-zero padding bits can happen easily.**  This ISO C++ change seems hard to implement on machines with hardware CAS, not LL/SC.  ISO C++ has historically been *very* conservative about any change that can't easily be supported on existing mainstream ISAs so this seems strange unless there's some trick they had in mind that I'm not seeing.

In *most* cases it won't be harmful to use the existing behaviour, and could be swept under the rug as being allowed by the "as-if" rule when it happens in a CAS retry loop that uses the last-seen value of the object as the "desired".  Same goes for `atomic<T>`.

But that doesn't apply for code that creates a new `T` and uses it as the "expected" arg to a CAS, or where each CAS failure has visible side-effects.

---

For `atomic<T>` (not `atomic_ref<T>`), it might be possible to implement the proposed C++20 change (CAS compares values, not memcmp object-representations) without hurting performance for non-atomic objects: Ensure padding bits/bytes are always in the same canonical state, `0` being the obvious choice.

Sanitize / canonicalize the padding bits in the `atomic<T>` constructor, and in every new value used with `store`, `exchange` and CAS.

C++20 also changes the default constructor for `std::atomic<T>` from being trivial (no initialization except for zero-init of static storage) to (C++20) value-initializing the underlying object with T(), i.e. zero for primitive types.  (C++20 also deprecates [`std::atomic_init`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_init), which nobody used because it was a clunky design.)

So I *think* we can assume that every `std::atomic<T>` object has been constructed by a `std::atomic<T>` constructor.  The possible problem is that some existing code might just cast a pointer to `atomic<T>*` and use it without using placement-new.  If that's officially Undefined Behaviour in C++20, then it's that code's problem (especially if it has any expectations about what CAS will do on a T with padding).

The C++20 constructors should ensure that any padding is zeroed, not just value bits.  Further atomic operations shouldn't change this, as long as CAS ensures that `desired` is similarly canonical.  And `exchange` and `store` similarly sanitize / canonicalize their inputs if they contain any padding bits.

On x86-64, I think the only primitive type with padding is 10-byte `long double` on x86-64 System V; on Windows it's the same as `double`.

---

As discussed in comments, this canonicalization could maybe take the form of widening stores to the part of the object that comes right before the padding.  e.g. x86-64 `struct { int i; void *p; }` access to `.i` could do a 64-bit store to make sure the 32 bits of padding after the `int` were zeroed.

Relying on this for objects in memory would have to be part of the ABI, but if we only do it as part of store, exchange, and CAS then it wouldn't have to be ABI-visible for normal objects.  But yes, it would be an ABI change to require it for `atomic<T>`

---

### Original answer, not accounting for the C++20 change

This is more like guidelines for how to make a nice C++17 implementation; I hadn't really read the C++20 change when I wrote this, I was thinking of it as a "nice to have", not a standards requirement.
Some of this might still be useful.  I think it's impossible to have full safety for `atomic_ref` without efficiency problems (in all code touching a struct with padding).  So IMO this should probably remain a minor wart.

**If you're ever writing padding bits explicitly, write them as zero when convenient.**  (i.e. when you have to make up some padding bits to go with some fresh value bits.)  If some other code happens to use `atomic_ref<>` on this object, they'll avoid spurious CAS failure on the first iteration if your `expected` also uses zeros for the padding bits.

Don't leave padding unwritten when first initializing an object; e.g. widen a dword store to qword to cover both an `int` and the alignment-padding before a `void*` in a struct.  Usually that will let you store zeros for basically free.

But don't let this stop you from optimizing copies of such objects into SIMD `movdqa` or whatever (i.e. memcpy); if it would take extra work to canonicalize the padding bits to zero, don't do it.  Hopefully they'll already be zero, and in the rare case they're not, a CAS will sort it out if one is ever used on this object.

Don't make the common case worse (for non-atomic objects) just because of the existence of `atomic_ref`.  **If people use CAS_weak or CAS_strong on a C++ object with padding, they need to be prepared for the possibility of spurious failure due to mismatched padding.**  This is a real thing that can happen on other C++ implementations, so making less efficient code in other places to make it impossible is a bad idea.

---

> This seem to defeat the purpose of the division between strong and weak CAS, since weak CAS should not consistently fail, and with this approach it may

**To avoid spurious failures**: Make sure that `expected = x.load()` loads the correct padding bits, not just the value bits, so an `x.CAS(expected, desired)` will succeed if `x` hasn't changed.  Most CAS on objects with padding start by loading the old value.

Also when CAS updates `expected`, make sure that updates the padding bits in the object, same as a load.  (It's important that both ways work: some badly written (or more complex) CAS retry loops do a `.load` inside the loop, instead of using the `expected` from the last attempt.)

**In the majority of cases, that avoids spurious failure due to padding bits, or at worst causes one retry as the padding bits are updated.**  That seems fine.

But possibly you'd want to do `tmp = x.load()` and mutate that `tmp` before using that as the *expected* for the next CAS, maybe to wait for some other thread to have done something.  Or create a `tmp` from scratch.

If we allow the compiler to re-generate the padding bits in `tmp` when it's modified, we could have CAS failure that a valid loop will never escape from.  **This is arguably the code's fault for doing that on an object with padding, so IDK if this is something compilers really need to handle.**  Ideally the optimizer should see that a value is being used as an "expected" for CAS and preserve padding when mutating, but that's only practical in limited cases.

I don't know how practical this hypothetical example is.  In most cases a programmer can avoid it by simply filling the padding in a struct with a dummy variable, or using a wider integer type.  x87 `long double` is a possible problem, though; on x86-64 System V it has `sizeof(long double) == 16`, with 6 of those bytes being padding.  So you can't put your own bytes there.

---

Related: Intel's compiler apparently has a bug where `memcmp` is optimized into a compare of just the value bits, for a `struct` containing `int` and `void*`.  So memcmp can say they're equal, but then CAS fails: [compare_exchange_strong failing despite data matching expected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534305/compare-exchange-strong-failing-despite-data-matching-expected-value).  I think this *is* a real bug; ISO C++ says `memcmp` compares the full object representation, same as what CAS does.  I think ISO C++ nails down enough about padding bits that on a given implementation you can know they exist and where they are, so there isn't room for the as-if rule to pretend that they changed value between C++ statements.

---

> LL/SC CAS

Yes, I'd recommend only comparing based on value bits if you have to do it manually to implement CAS on top of LL/SC.  That's probably what most people really want.  (Unless that makes the code less efficient, e.g. with bitfields.  If it's a lot easier to just compare a whole register, do that instead of e.g. unpacking a byte and 16-bit element from a 32-bit register.)

Comment: Thanks. The context was as follows: MSVC implemented (non-atomic) `__builtin_zero_non_value_bits` to use in constructor, I convinced maintainers that this intrinsic should be used to generate the mask for CAS retries instead, it worked (optimized to mask comparison). But I started hesitating on my own. There's my PR https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/1029 . LL/SC is just of curiosity for now, there's no intrinsic to inject mask in LL/SC (yet)

Comment: I think there is an easy way to obtain accidentally non-zero padding bits, see my edit

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: Updated this to try to address the question better.  It's still not really worth accepting, IMO, but it's at least in good enough shape for me to leave it here for future readers.  i.e. I wrote down a lot of what I can think of to say.

Comment: What would you think about using CAS only twice for `atomic_ref`: if fails due to padding, zero it (atomic and or bytewise store) and retry just once. Together with normalization of params to load / store / exchange, should work.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: Ideally you could optimize that away in CAS retry loops where letting the C logic retry would have no visible side-effects.  But yes, that should be possible since you can save you can save the old `expected` and manually compare against the current value on failure.  Good idea.  That costs extra instructions to save a reg or regs you'd rather not have on the fast path, and it only works when inlining (so you know which bits are value bits and which are padding).  But hopefully most uses of atomic<T> are on objects without padding.